# How can I query which actions have been assigned to individual error numbers on SRS?

Tags: replication, sybase

> The DBA can modify the default rowcount mismatch behavior by assigning a different action to the corresponding error number in the replication server error class (see the assign action command for more details).
>   (*from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190339/35503) regarding replication errors*)

The question arises: **how can I (not a DBA) query out what actions have been assigned to individual error numbers**?

If possible I would prefer a solution that works from ASE side without having to have access to replication server.

Comment: Obviously, I'm asking for a technical solution, not a social "as your friendly DBA team" one :)

Comment: the information about error numbers and associated actions is stored in the SRS's system database (aka: Replication Server System Database; aka: RSSD); highly doubtful the DBA is going to grant access to the RSSD to non-DBAs :-)   ... of course, there's the question of why a non-DBA would want this list if, as is standard/default setup, only DBAs have access to the SRS instance and associated errorlog (ie, only DBAs are going to know if/when the DSI goes down and why) ...

Comment: @markp - to know if a weird architecture that deletes different sets of rows on source and target would cause SRS to suspend DSI connection as per your answer (which, personally, I don't find to be a desired outcome. I suspect DBAs wouldn't either :)

Comment: ultimately you need input from the DBAs ... what actions are assigned to various error numbers/issues ... is rowcount mismatch disabled on the target database in question ... how to proceed if rowcount mismatches are ok for some tables but not ok for other tables (ie, rowcount mismatch error actions are assigned at the db level and not the table leve)